# Why did SwiftMailer send via localhost

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

We have a cron set up in Symfony 1.4 to send out several emails each morning. For some reason, today, it attempted to send via localhost rather than via the SMTP server we have configured in factories.yml. We don't have localhost on the production server so naturally this failed.

A couple new things that happened:

1. we actually replaced the cron yesterday with new code ... but the new code is using the same project / mailer configuration as the old one, so I don't see how this could cause a problem.
2. there are some new members on the team, from another company, and they have only recently gotten server access / started committing code. I can't see any changes made to factories.yml ...

Any idea what might be causing this? Any hints on where to search?

Comment: Check the calling code / application config to ensure it's still set to use SMTP and that it's configured correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to empty your cache ?

Comment: aaaaaand clearing the cache took care of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear your cache

```
php symfony cc
```